# Type Mismatch Error 13 When Looping Through Range Containing Formulae

Tags: excel, vba

I have adapted a macro to loop through a range but am getting the above error when I try to run it.

The macro worked when the range contained numbers but the new range contains formulae.

Is that what is causing the problem? If so, how do I amend the macro so it works?

Thanks

```
Sub HighlightMatrixStats()
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim sngCell As Single

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Matrix")
   
    For r = 6 To 30
      For c = 4 To 78
         If .Cells(5, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) >= .Cells(5, c) * 1.05 And .Cells(r, c) < .Cells(5, c) * 1.1 Then .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 222, 241)
      Next c
   Next r
   
   For r = 6 To 30
      For c = 4 To 78
         If .Cells(5, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) >= .Cells(5, c) * 1.1 And .Cells(r, c) < .Cells(5, c) * 1.15 Then .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
      Next c
   Next r
   
    For r = 6 To 30
      For c = 4 To 78
         If .Cells(5, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) >= .Cells(5, c) * 1.15 Then .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(110, 145, 208)
      Next c
   Next r
   
    For r = 6 To 30
      For c = 4 To 78
         If .Cells(5, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <= .Cells(5, c) * 0.95 And .Cells(r, c) > .Cells(5, c) * 0.9 Then .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(237, 219, 236)
      Next c
   Next r
   
   For r = 6 To 30
      For c = 4 To 78
         If .Cells(5, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <= .Cells(5, c) * 0.9 And .Cells(r, c) > .Cells(5, c) * 0.85 Then .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(223, 189, 221)
      Next c
   Next r
   
   For r = 6 To 30
      For c = 4 To 78
         If .Cells(5, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <= .Cells(5, c) * 0.85 Then .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(207, 157, 205)
      Next c
   Next r

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Is that what is causing the problem?` - no. But apparently some of the formulas return errors. You cannot compare errors to other things.

Comment: Thanks GSerg. I've double checked and the formulas are ok.

Comment: Firstly, no need of so many iterations. You can include all `If`s in the first iteration. Then, the formulas themselves should not make the code returning an error. But if they are wrong built and return, let us say, "aa12" (or " ") you cannot multiply their return. Please check (moving the cursor over all cells value) what does them show, being on error (on the yellow code line). Especially in the area where a math operation is done (multiplication). If not an error, you should find a wrong (string) result of the formula, I think...

Comment: Does the error appear at the first iteration?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, thanks, yes it does.

Comment: And, did you try checking the involved cells value? Does everything  show as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the format of your tests to something like this, which will prevent the code stopping and will alert you to the location of errors:

```
For r = 6 To 30
    For c = 4 To 78
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(5, c).Value) And IsNumeric(.Cells(r, c).Value) Then
            If .Cells(r, c).Value >= .Cells(5, c).Value * 1.05 And .Cells(r, c).Value < .Cells(5, c).Value * 1.1 Then .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(211, 222, 241)
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error on column " & c & ", row " & r
        End If
    Next c
Next r
```

This uses the `IsNumeric` function, which returns `FALSE` if there is an error or the cell contains text etc. that would cause a multiplication fail. By placing your test inside this test, as opposed to as part of this (with an `IF.. AND ..`) means your test does not get run if it returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks guys. CLR;s code is showing errors in rows at the bottom of the range, starting 19 columns in, but I can't seem to find the reason. I copied down the formulas and ran again and got the same thing.

Comment: I've added an image of the range to the question, if it helps. Thanks

Comment: As an experiment I added On Error Resume Next and the code worked almost as expected. The only issue came when there is no values in row 5 and rows 6-30. I thought my code dealt with that with this line:  If .Cells(5, c) <> "" And .Cells(r, c) <> "" ?

Comment: Odd. Empty cells should have a `.Value` of zero. You could try adding the following line after the `Error on Column` line: `Debug.Print "Cell " & .Cells(r, c).Address & " formula is: " & .Cells(r, c).Formula` so the debug window shows you what is causing the error..?